# Serializing object to database

Tags: java

I know we can wrap `FileOutputstream` in `ObjectoutputStream`, `FileInputStream` in `ObjectInputStream` and use `ObjectOutputstream.writeObject` and `ObjectInputstream.readobject()` methods to serialize Java objects to a file.

If instead of a file I want to serialize the object to a database then all I would need to do is call `setObject()` method of `PreparedStatement` to write the object and `getObject()` of `ResultSet` to retrieve the object.

If the class for the object we are attempting to serialize has not implemented the `Serializable` interface then in case of serializing the object to file we will get a `NotSerializableException`

However in case of serializing the object to DB since we are not at all using `writeObject` but just using `PreparedStatement setObject` method,so the JVM will throw any exception if class is not `Serializable`.

So does this mean that while serializing object to database it is not necessary to implement `Serializable` interface?

Answer (score 0):

No, you must still implement `Serializable` since the JDBC library would attempt to call `writeObject`.

On a side note, I'm not sure if serializing the whole object into database works well all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know `setObject()` takes serialize object as input and get object also returns `java.io.Serializable`type.

`void setObject(java.io.Serializable object)`

`java.io.Serializable getObject()`

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code of Mysql jdbc preparedStatement.Following is link:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java.html

I found that in the setObject() method  the setSerializableObject method is called which finally calls the writeObject() method of ObjectOutputStream. Also this method wraps exception in SQLException so I guess if the object is not serializable we will get an SQLException.